# Get multiple text messages which get split by the carriers (160 char limit) from twilio

Tags: php, sms, twilio

We are using the twilio account get receive sms
The problem is we are saving those sms in our db. We are not able to get any exact field which can help us in identifying that whether the sms was sent as two different messages. As twilio is sending that as different sms with different ids.
Basically here is the math
SMS=SMS1 + SMS2

twilio gives SMS1 as different id and SMS2 as different id
and there is no field which will tell me that SMS1 + SMS2 =SMS

thnx

Answer (score 1):

Yep... I noticed the same thing. My workaround was to defer processing on the receiving host for about 5 seconds -- after which time all such carrier-split pieces would have arrived.

The splitting is done at the carrier (BEFORE it reaches Twilio) -- so Twilio is just acting as "pass-through" for the split pieces, which feels like the right call design-wise.